# Cannot send data to firestore

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore

I have a data where the data is taken from csv. When i toast all data from csv, the data is appears like Mainan Anak, Kaos Pollo, Sepatu Lari, Kaos Gym. The problem is when i want to send data to firestore, the data cannot be sent to firestore. I check in Logcat, no error appears at all.

MyCSV :

[image: 1]

Code :

```
private void readCSVFile(String csvNameFile) {
    try {
        File readFolderCSV = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Download/" + csvNameFile);
        CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(readFolderCSV.getAbsoluteFile()));
        String[] nextLine;
        while ((nextLine = csvReader.readNext()) != null) {
            final String UoMID = collectionReference.document().getId();

            final ModelUoM modelUoM = new ModelUoM(UoMID, nextLine[0]);
            modelUoM.setUoMID(UoMID);
            modelUoM.setUoMName(nextLine[0]);

            // Check if UoM is already exist
            collectionReference.whereEqualTo("uoMName", nextLine[0]).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        for (DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot : task.getResult()) {
                            if (documentSnapshot.exists()) {
                                Toast.makeText(MasterUoM.this, "UoM is already exist", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                progressAddUoM.dismiss();
                            } else {
                                // Cannot send data to firestore
                                collectionReference.document(UoMID).set(modelUoM).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                        Toast.makeText(MasterUoM.this, "UoM successfully added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        progressAddUoM.dismiss();
                                        dialogAddFile.dismiss();

                                        finish();
                                        overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
                                        startActivity(getIntent());
                                        overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
                                    }
                                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                        Toast.makeText(MasterUoM.this, "Error : " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        progressAddUoM.dismiss();
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(MasterUoM.this, "Error : " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    progressAddUoM.dismiss();
                }
            });
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(MasterUoM.this, "The specified file was not found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        progressAddUoM.dismiss();
    }
}
```

Comment: If you replace the while CSV reading and parsing with a single, simple write to Firestore as shown [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#set_a_document), does the write work? If not, the problem has nothing to do with the CSV parsing, and you can significantly simplify the question (thus making it more likely that someone can help or that you spot the problem yourself). See [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: are you sure to your rules in firestore?